# Using hidesBarsOnTap with UICollectionView selection

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` where only some of the cells are selectable.  I want tapping on any other cells, as well as anywhere else on the screen, to invoke the navigation bar hiding/revealing behavior.

When I set `navigationController.hidesBarsOnTap = true`, the `barHideOnTapGestureRecognizer` consumes the taps so the user can't select an item in the collection view.  How can I have both the bar hiding behavior and normal collection view selection behavior?

If I set `barHideOnTapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false`, then both the item is selected and the bar hiding toggles, but I want only the former.

I can't do anything in the `barHideOnTapGestureRecognizer` delegate as Apple explicitly says not to.

`UICollectionView` doesn't use a gesture recognizer to do its selection, so there's no way to set up dependencies between that and the `barHideOnTapGestureRecognizer`.

The only thing that comes to mind is to manage the collection selection manually with a tap gesture recognizer covering the whole collection (Apple says not to put them on individual cells), but it seems crazy to duplicate all the collection view selection.  I've gotta be missing something.  Please, help me see the light! :)

Answer (score 2):

In the end, I added a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the `UICollectionView`, and set the recognizer's delegate to return `true` from `shouldReceiveTouch` only if the touch was within a cell I wanted to be selectable.

```
 func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    for visibleCell in collectionView.visibleCells() {
        if let selectableCell = visibleCell as? SelectableCell
            where touch.view!.isDescendantOfView(selectableCell) {
                return true
        }
    }
    return false
 }
```

Thus, the recognizer will fire only for touches in cells I want to be selectable, leaving all other touches within the collection view to be picked up by the `barHideOnTapGestureRecognizer`.

In the tap gesture recognizer's triggered action, I use hit testing on the `visibleCells` to locate the selected cell, and invoke the selection.

I had to set `navigationController.barHideOnTapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = true` to prefer the gesture recognizer on the collection view for touches.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. `barHideOnTapGestureRecognizer` would intercept taps on cells and let them through, so the bars were toggled and the collectionView received a `didSelectCell` delegate message.
I solved it by adding my own `UITapGestureRecognizer` to a `UIView` and make that view the `backgroundView` of the collectionView. In the action the bars are manually toggled. So when the user taps a cell my recognizer on the background view wouldn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has haunted me until I got the following solution.

We don't want to handle collection view events with our own gesture if possible. The idea is to use our own gesture recognizer, instead of barHideOnTapGestureRecognizer, to toggle bars. We can always restore the default recognizer by setting `navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true` later. Here are the details.

1. Disable/Restore the default gesture

   ```
   override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = false
   }

   override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
       navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true
   }
   ```
2. Add your own gesture

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       // other set up
       let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(toggleBarsOnTap(sender:)))
       // need the following otherwise your collection view cannot receive touch event
       gesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
       view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
   }
   ```
3. your gesture handler

   ```
   @objc private func toggleBarsOnTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
       let loc = sender.location(in: yourCollectionView)
       let shouldToggle = YOUR_LOGIC_TO_CHECK_WHETHER_TOGGLE_SHOULD_BE_INVOKED_AT_LOC
       if let isHidden = navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden, shouldToggle {
           let action = !isHidden
           navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(action, animated: true)
           navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(action, animated: true)
       }
   }
   ```